# How to make a enum type using Doctrine and Symfony 6 with PHP 8.1?

Tags: php, symfony, enums, syntax, doctrine

A rookie programmer here. Im trying to know how to make a enum type with 3 choices in Symfony 6 but I dont know if is possible with a terminal and commands. I would greatly appreciate if someone could give me an example syntax using Symfony 6 in case it cannot be done through the console.

Comment: What do you mean with "using Doctrine", why can you not just do a regular enum ?

Answer (score 0):

So that's very simple, I guess you would like to use this Enum in a form. You can create this PHP file Enum in this namespace "App\Enum" which corresponds to the path "src/Enum" (create this folder). The code might look like this :

```php
// some example

namespace App\Enum;

enum Colors: string {
    case Red = 'Red';
    case Green = 'Green';
}
```

and in your form the code might look like this :

```php
use App\Enum\Colors;

$builder->add('colors', EnumType::class, ['class' => Colors::class]);

// or more simply you can use "ChoiceType::class" in ur form

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

$builder->add('colors', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices'  => [
        'Red' => 'Red',
        'Green' => 'Grenn',
        'SomeValue' => 'SomeValue',
    ],
]);
```